# How to use ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW to avoid OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap, broadcastreceiver

I found in one post regarding OutOfMemoryError(mainly due to BITMAP) that it can be Notified with Broadcastreceiver (ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW) when Heap is going to full. Can any one tell how to implement this broadcast Receiver and avoid OutOfMemoryError?

Answer (score 4):

ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW notifies you that the space on the phone's permanent storage is running low.  It has nothing to do with space on your application's heap, so you cannot use it for this purpose.